# What tools and processes are available for effective Trunk-Based Development?

Tags: git, github, version-control, dvcs

At my company, we are using git-flow, and having many branches and PRs is often confusing, and slows down development.  It is especially unnecessary during the startup phase of a project.

One problem is that most features take more than 1 or 2 days to complete. If there is a code review process, this can take another day or two. If there are multiple developers working on separate branches for several days in an immature (rapidly changing) codebase, there is a lot of opportunities for the branches to diverge, leading to merge conflicts, duplication of effort, etc.  Sometimes a branch is created off another feature branch that has not yet been merged for some reason.  This is also prone to errors, for example a PR can have the wrong "base branch".  Sometimes after a PR is merged I try to merge trunk/master into my feature branch, and this has led to painful merges, where every file modified shows up as a conflict.

However, some kind of code-review practice is necessary, so I want to know what other teams and companies have used.

I could imagine a system where a feature is identified by a tag in the commit message.  For example "[XYZ-1234] added new component". The tag identifies the ticket, and the message gives more details. So everyone could be committing to a "dev" branch, and synchronizing often, and when a feature is determined to be complete, all the commits associated with that feature could be code reviewed then merged into "master" (by searching the commit messages).  This seems simpler and better to me, so I'm not sure why a system like this is not created and used.

Comment: Hello, I see 3 people voted to close this question.  Can someone please clarify why?  I believe this is an important, and totally valid question.

Comment: Can you show the detail git-flow you are using? Even all the developers work on the development branch (such as `dev` branch), it shouldn't slow down the development, since they are working on the latest version.

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT every developer has their own feature branch.  Sometimes multiple branches.  These branches sometimes live for a week or multiple weeks!  Eventually, everything gets merged into master. Sometimes one PR contains changes that are already superseded in another PR (which is confusing).  If I create a branch off master, it will be missing a lot of important changes.

Comment: You can create a branch for all developers co-work on the branch, and then create PR to merge this branch into `master` branch instead. And added the details as an answer, and you can have a try.

Comment: A pull request workflow will generally work best for you here. Your problem is that your features are too large. Keep your branch flow, make your features smaller, and your problem will go away. Trunk-based development with Git is a bad idea for lots of reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, it seems all the developers are work own theirs own feature  branches, and then the create PRs to merge the feature branches into master branch.

And for the suggestions, you should **create a branch such as `dev` for all developers to co-work on the branch**. And the work flow as below:

- All the developers work on theirs own `feature` branches.
- When developers finish their work, they should merge their `feature` branches into `dev` branch.
- Then create a PR to merge `dev` into `master` branch.
- And for the next time when developers develop new work, they can create new `feature` branches from `dev` branch. And since some `feature` branches may live for a few weeks and there may have new changes on `dev` branch during the weeks, developers can rebase these `feature` branches on the top of latest `dev` branch by executing `git pull origin dev --rebase` command on `feature` branches.

Comment: That is what Git-flow process recommends in this page (http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/).  However, the main problem is that most features take more than one or two days, and my company has a policy that we need to finish to do a code review, which can take another day or two.  Particularly during the early phases of a project, multiple branches that are open for several days have lots of opportunities to diverge, sometimes it leads to duplication of work, etc.  The only way to prevent this is to synchronize more often, but the Git/PR process does not allow this.

Comment: How do you do a code review, on one's `feature` branch? It's more reasonable to view code and create PR from `dev` branch. And it can make all developers work more efficient.

Comment: If you create PR from dev branch, multiple developers are committing directly to dev? So when you do code review, can you know who's code you are reviewing?  Will the author of the code be notified about reviews on their code?  I don't know because I never tried it, we always have only one developer for each PR. 

Also, every time you merge a PR, I thought you have to delete that branch after merging, so I'm not sure how you can multiple PRs from a dev branch.

Comment: PR for merging a `feature` branch into `master` is developer-level and  merging `dev` branch into `master` branch is team-level. PR to merge `dev` into `master` branch is not focus on who make changes but how make changes. This can also prevent the duplicated work among different developers. And the `feature` branches can be deleted after merging into `dev` since the `feature` branches are private for different developers. While you should not delete `dev` branch after merging into `master` branch since `dev` is the common branch used for all developers.

Comment: Besides, you can search for multiple for flows (branching models), you will find `dev` branch is necessary, and merging feature branches into master will truly increase your work.

Comment: @Marina You’ve got it backwards. It’s better to do code reviews from feature branches, *before* they’re merged into a dev branch. (Tools like GitHub and GitLab make this very easy.)

Answer (score 0):

A normal trunk-base flow should serve well in your case.

The problem you are facing could possibly be soothed by some extra practices.

1. Pain in merge conflict

   - here we assume the feature branch are not shared
   - developer should frequently merge master (assuming you are using master as trunk) into their feature branch, or frequently rebase their feature branch on latest master.
   - Before pull request really merged back to master, try rebasing/squashing to lastest master.  This keep master history more linear.
2. Feature branch based on another feature branch

   - I expect here you are sharing a feature branch.  Try to avoid it if possible.  It makes your merging and handling easier
3. feature branch naming

   - I'd have the feature branch name and commit message all contains the ticket number. Coz feature branch will be gone after feature is completed so you can only refer to your commit message to identify what changes is related to which issue.

Not sure if it helps